# Escape 'escape character' in between double quotes in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have python code in String format

```
"input = \"1\n2\t3\n4\"\nprint(input)"
```

I want to escape any characters that only occur between double quotes or single quote.

The final string should look like this

```
"input = \"1\\n2\\t3\n4\"\nprint(input)"
```

I tried doing this but doesn't work.

```
code.replaceAll("(\")[\n\t\b]*(\")", "\"\\n\"")
```

Comment: `"\n"` is not a two char string, it is a single LF, newline char. You can't escape the backslash there as there is no backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all characters after a quote (") that are non-quotes, up to the next quote.

Regex to find all texts between two quotes:

```
"[^"]*"

||   ||
||   |and terminated with a "
||   MANY repeatations of that (written as *)
|characters that are NOT " (written as [^"])
Start with "
```

But now you don't want ONE finding for such a string between " and " - you want each character to be a unique finding.

At this point, standard regex can't do the job for you:
You could get just the first character of such a finding with `"([^"])[^"]*"` but then your next question is how to get 2nd, 3rd etc finding. You might think about adding variable-length identifiers before and after the match.. but even with a regex like `"[^"]*([^"])[^"]*"` you will always get just ONE match for the finding between both "". Regex does not support a concept of looping through findings; wildcards are always evaluated as max-match.

So you will need something different.
I'd recommend to search for first position of " within your string, e.g. with String.indexOf(...) and then loop through the string until you find the next (terminating) quote.
For all characters in between, you can replace it.
You will therefore work with a separate data output variable.